# WebStorm file watcher for 1 extension within a file type

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I am trying to setup syntax highlighting and a file watcher for a new file extension from within WebStorm. The `.rt` file extension represents a React template (see http://wix.github.io/react-templates/).

React Templates are essentially HTML files with syntactic sugar for ReactJS. The RT files should have all the syntax highlighting of an HTML page, but then need to be transpiled by the RT transpiler.

- If I create a new RT file type in WebStorm, I can create a file watcher to launch the RT transpiler for a specific file extension, but since it's a new file type I lose all of the standard HTML syntax highlighting.
- If I register the RT extension to the HTML file type, I get syntax highlighting, but then WebStorm runs all HTML files through the RT file watcher and transpiler.

I either need a way to specify a single file extension (not WebStorm file type) for the WebStorm file watcher or I need a way to easily create a new WebStorm file type that is based off an existing file type so that I do not have enter all of the HTML reserved words for my new file type. Is either solution possible?

I realize I could use a command line grunt or gulp script to run the file watcher, but I'd really like to do this all inside WebStorm.

Comment: I have found a WebStorm plugin that answers my immediate need for an RT file watcher and syntax highlighting (see http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7648). I should have checked the plugin repository before posting my question.

Although I no longer need the WebStorm capability I described for React templates, my basic questions still remain: 1) Can I create a file watcher for 1 file extension within a file type? and 2) Can I create a file type based off an existing file type?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can associate *.rt extension with 'HTML' file type and create a custom scope with only .rt files included in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes. Then choose this custom scope in your file watcher settings, 'Scope:' field
2. No. You can either create a new file type and define your own syntax highlighting rules (from scratch - there is no way to reuse HTML highlighting there), or search for existing textmate bundles for this file type, import them and use for syntax highlighting, or search for existing plugins/develop your own plugin for this language.